# strange output for UIPickerView

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have tab based application , I need when click on button a pickerview appear as action sheet

I use the following code

```
-(IBAction)DisplayPicker:(id)sender{

    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];  
    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 20, 20);  
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES; 
    pickerView.dataSource = self; 
    pickerView.delegate = self;  
    [actionSheet addSubview:pickerView]; 
    [pickerView release];  
    UISegmentedControl *closeButton = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"Close"]]; 
    closeButton.momentary = YES;  
    closeButton.frame = CGRectMake(260, 7.0f, 50.0f, 30.0f); 
    closeButton.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar; 
    closeButton.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor]; 
    [closeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissActionSheet:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged]; 
    [actionSheet addSubview:closeButton]; 
    [closeButton release];  
    [actionSheet showInView:self.view];  
    [actionSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)]; 
}
```

the problem when click on the button a line appear , not the pickerview

How to solve that please , I develop for ipad 
I use the following delegate function

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView;
{
    return 1;
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    NSLog( [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row] )  ;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [arrayNo count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
{
    return [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

where I initialized arrayNo  using

```
arrayNo = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[arrayNo addObject:@" 100 "];
[arrayNo addObject:@" 200 "];
[arrayNo addObject:@" 400 "];
[arrayNo addObject:@" 600 "];
[arrayNo addObject:@" 1000 "];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is that your frame for the picker is not big enough. I usually start with 325 and 250 for a picker and go from there. So your line to set the frame should maybe be this.

```
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 40, 325, 250);
```

Comment: it appeaered apart of the picker but not all of it , even after increasing it , you can try it

Comment: When I paste your code into a new project it displays the picker correctly as long as I comment out the lines that set the dataSource and delegate to self. If you comment out those lines and then the picker is the correct size (but empty) then you should look at your datasource and delegate methods.

Comment: I updated the question with the delegate function I use , could u help me in that

Comment: They behave differently on the iPad (Action Sheets that is). On the iPad, I ususally create the view in IB and then display it as a popover or as a UIModal.